# Drag and Drop из listbox в listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть 2 `listbox`. Смысл в том чтобы строку из одного перетащить в другой. Если можно хотя бы с простыми примерами... Использую `WinForms`. Как использовать drag and drop из `listbox1` в `listbox2`?

Comment: Какая GUI технология используется? WPF, WinForms?

Comment: А что если воспользовтаься этим? :)  http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/rows/drag-and-drop

Comment: @Side Kick, Если вы разобрались с вопросом, вы можете самостоятельно дать ответ к нему.